# "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" compilando imagen docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, gemfile

Estoy tratando de compilar una imagen Docker basada en la imagen ruby:3.0.  En el Dockerfile, al ejecutar "RUN bundle install", comienza a instalar las dependencias hasta que muestra el error:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> #10 34.20
> #10 34.20     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5/ext/tiny_tds
> #10 34.20 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
> #10 34.20 ./siteconf20220804-7-s3hvms.rb extconf.rb
> #10 34.20 looking for freetds headers in the following directories:
> #10 34.20  - /opt/local/include
> #10 34.20  - /opt/local/include/freetds
> #10 34.20  - /usr/local/include
> #10 34.20  - /usr/local/include/freetds
> #10 34.20 looking for freetds library in the following directories:
> #10 34.20  - /opt/local/lib
> #10 34.20  - /opt/local/lib/freetds
> #10 34.20  - /usr/local/lib
> #10 34.20  - /usr/local/lib/freetds

Normalmente eso en Linux se soluciona instalando algunos headers files propios de la distribución que se está usando, pero en este caso no sé cómo hacerlo.

El archivo Dockerfile está así:

```
FROM ruby:3.0

## throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN gem i bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

CMD ["rails c"]
```

Intenté agregando esto en el Dockerfile, pero me dio otro error:

```
RUN apt-get install ruby-dev
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Pero esa imagen ruby:3.0 también debería estar basada en linux, deberías agregar los mismos comandos con RUN para instalar las dependencias antes de llamar a bundle install

Comment: Lo intenté con apt-get, pero no tengo claro qué paquetes instalar en esa distribución.  Intenté y me salía que no encontraba el paquete que yo trataba de instalar.